# Slider with stack images in the left and text in the right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

[View This Image for Better Understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QavqR.png)

Is this possible using Slick Slider ? If yes Please Add codepen demo

I tried centre mode but that was working only with images not for the text in the right.

How to move both the left and right section onlick of numbers simultaneously

This is what i have tried:
https://codepen.io/jabirgct/pen/LYXRmJg

```
    $('.container').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  infinite: true,
  arrows: true,
  rows: 0,
  dots: true,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  edgeFriction: 0.2
})
```

Comment: Not a CSS guy so you need to fix CSS in better way,but let me know do you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/jb0edzrf/

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant This is a simple slider , i need to stack the images three at the same time

Comment: then add three images inside each div and then ask A designer to make it in your way

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant but i need this effect https://codepen.io/jabirgct/pen/gOQweBd